# IE 7 and 8 not showing perfect design view

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have a problem in IE 7, 8.

I am showing 3 products / row, in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE 9,10,11

It shows me perfect design. BUT in IE 7,8 it change complete product design.

I don't get any idea how to get perfect product view in IE 7, 8

How can i do this ?

Comment: this may be a float issue or position issue you are facing can drop a link or markup or jsfiddle will be helpful to debug

Comment: can you provide the html/css?

Comment: Sorry bro no link no code -- but i work on css complete and in IE 9 10 11 it shows me perfect view but in IE 7 8 it shows me all products in one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I absolutely hate IE, specially versions 6, 7 and 8. When you are designing a wordpress theme, you have to style it twice, once for proper browsers and then for the IE ancients. The other big thing to remember, these ancients don't have support for media queries.

So to solve your problem, create a stylesheet called `ie.css`. You will use this to do all your styling for IE 7 and 8.

Next you will need to enqueue that stylesheet, but we will enqueue it conditionally. This stylesheet will only load for IE versions up to IE8. So in your functions.php, add the following

```
function enqueque_ie_stylesheet() {
// Load the Internet Explorer specific.  stylesheet.
 wp_enqueue_style( 'style-ie',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/ie.css',   array(), '' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'style-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ie_stylesheet' );
```

You can now add your styles in `ie.css`. Just remember to change `get_template_directory_uri` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` if you are using a child theme

Comment: hi @Pieter Goosen, thanx to your answer i achieved 80%, but my my products are showing in one line i want to show them 3 products/row. can u help me

Comment: Glad I could be of help. You will need to go and check which elements are giving you the desired layout in the original stylesheet and then copy that to your ie.css. It will be something that has a width of between 30 and 33 percent. Unfortunately I can't tell you exactly where as I don't know your theme. Inspect your theme in google chrome and check which elemnts are related. I would think that should be something inside a media query. Remember, IE7 and 8 don't accept that. So if you copy code inside a media query, don't copy the media query, just the stuff inside

Comment: If you don't come right, please add a link to your site. Will see what I can get from that

Comment: thanx alot bro - its done, actually i made some mistakes after paste ur code so i figure out and ITS DONE - +2

Comment: My pleasure. Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS hack. The “hack” is the \9 following the value and preceding the closing semicolon. This will target IE8 and below.

Example:

```
.element {  
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
    margin-bottom: 10px\9;  
}
```

Comment: Although your code might work, the problem lies inside media queries. IE7 and 8 will simply ignore any styling within a media query, even if your method are used. That is a huge design flaw that nearly sunk IE

Comment: Agreed. The code is a workaround. Afterall one can't change the behavior of IE7.