# Page not displaying correctly in IE and Firefox due to CSS issue

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, firefox

My website is http://www.parentcenterhub.org/region6-aboutus/ This page is displaying correctly in Google Chrome. But, the layout is messed up for Internet Explorer and Firefox. I think this is CSS issue. The CSS code is

```
#primary { display: -webkit-box; // or display: flex; }
.entry-content img.alignleft {margin-left: 0px !important;}
.custom_list { float: right; display: inline-block;
width: 30%;
list-style-type: none; }
```

Comment: Go and have look at the question I answered here. Hope it sheds some light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678988/ie-7-and-8-not-showing-perfect-design-view/22679433#22679433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-webkit-box` will only work in webkit browsers - which Firefox/ IE are not. You need to specify the vendor prefixes for it to work in all modern browsers.

```
#primary { 
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

This however won't work on older versions of IE (as with everything else..). Check here http://caniuse.com/flexbox for information on what versions of browsers support this property.

Comment: I need it to work on IE 9 as mandatory requirement. So, how can I go about it?

Comment: use percentages as your widths instead. eg: `.main-content { width: 80%; }` and `.sidebar { width: 20%; }`

Comment: Yes, I have used percentages. I fixed the IE9 issue by using display: inline-block. But, there is also an overlapping issue for IE10. You can check it by entering URL parentcenterhub.org/region6-aboutus at netrenderer.com/index.php for IE10 -ms-flexbox isnt working. Please suggest what to do.