# Website links load but do not redirect to different page Wordpress, IE8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I've almost completed a website built in Wordpress, using a theme called WP Foocamp. My problem is that whilst the site looks great in most modern browsers, mobiles etc I am still struggling with IE8. I don't have an in-depth knowledge of javascript or PHP which makes this really difficult, but if I could find out where the problem is then I could research where to fix it.

Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated.

The url is ipswichhalfmarathon.com

Comment: I will add that I tested it in the markup validator, would this error have anything to do with the problem?
Line 35, Column 142: Element style not allowed as child of element header in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
…ative" /></div> <style type='text/css'>#rev_slider_2_1,#rev_slider_2_1_wrapper…

Comment: Please remove this comment, edit our question and update it there..

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a complete answer on the subject of IE pre 9. Go and check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22679433/1908141)