# How to load a separate IE8 style sheet in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

Due to not understanding the @import query for responsive behaviour IE8 is incorrectly displaying some of my wordpress website - http://dev1.markdavies.eu . To solve this I'd like to try having a separate style sheet for IE8/7/& 6 and have found the following code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css"/>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style-ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

However I don't know which php file I should put it in. Or even if this is the best way to go about.  Please could anyone advise.

I am using a child theme and am reasonably well conversed with the file structure and css, HTML and php code.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the header.php file of the theme?

Comment: FYI, some themes also use the `wp_enqueue_style()` method within `functions.php` to load a CSS file for older versions of IE.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22679433/1908141) I recently did about IE7/IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For child theme, use:

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="  <?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thank you Vel, this did the trick. Although it's not a child theme the header.php is using the echo get_stylesheet . .  form rather than the straight 'stylesheet url' form.

Answer (score 1):

Add the appropriate conditional comment to your theme’s header.php file right after the call to the theme’s default stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie7.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then upload your new IE-specific stylesheet (ie7.css in the example above) to your theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help everyone. Although it's not a child theme, the header.php uses the following form to call the style sheet;

```
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

So the last answer by vel did the trick.  I inserted the conditional statement as follows;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>    
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/style-ie.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Out of interest, does it matter if it goes before or after the 'ping back' line of code? It seems to work for me either way.

Comment: Update: my mistake, it is a child theme, I got confused between two different templates I am working on.