# Best way to optimize for IE8

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I have a website I made (http://ruzmarinskarosa.rs/wordpress/). It's a simple wordpress website based on my theme using underscorse. Now, I made the site how I want it and it looks great on all devices.

BUt on IE8 it just looks crap. What would be your best advice for me to optimize it for IE8?

It has media queries, border-radius and etc...

Comment: "What would be your best advice for me to optimize it for IE8?"

Don't.

Comment: If you want `css3` features -> http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: @TheHeadRush you really think it's not worth it? I heard there's some people still using that.

Comment: Unless the project is required to support a browser that does not support common standards, i really don't think it's worth the hassle. IMO, sometimes it's better to encourage users to modernize than it is to cater to their Luddite-ism.

Comment: IE8 is just as crap as IE6 and IE7. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22679433/1908141)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before resorting to plugins and things to polyfill or fix the code, do all you can do to make your regular html/css/js work. Sure IE8 doesn't support some things but there are many many ways to achieve solid layouts across browsers.

That being said, you metioned you had media queries, which simply are not supported. I use [RespondJS](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to get media queries working properly, which is mostly useful so that it picks up your intended styles and not just mobile.

selectivizr.com is another good one as the user above commented.

http://css3pie.com/ is another good compatibility plugin.

and in the future, try to show some examples of code you have tried, specific things that aren't working etc. Your question will be better received.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support media query, border radius or any CSS3 (or html5 for that matter). So you can just use some kind of determination like feature detection and serve a different html+stylesheet for this browser and similar older browsers.

rounded corners you can implement with a lot of divs and transparant png images. you wont need media queries as you can just serve the desktop version of your site if browser does not support it.

the other solution is to include a javascript solution to make up for IE8 being old. like IE9.js .